# Capture SMS events in nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am working on an application which need to get updated when an SMS received (with the content from SMS) and also do the cleanup when SMS is deleted from the mobile.

How to listen for these SMS events with nativescript ?

Comment: I don't think that has been implemented as a plugin yet. You will have to tap into the native APIs using a Broadcast Receiver in Android, and ??? on iOS (if that's at all possible) to implement the functionality.

Comment: iOS don't have this ability there isn''t any way to listen for sms there @pkanev

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-sms-inbox.  Seems to provide all features you require.

About the application updating itself - do not think this is possible with the above plugin, as it would constantly need to run in background, listening for SMS events.

How about at the same time the SMS is sent, a push notification is sent to the app?